# overwriting dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a given dataframe

new_df :

| ID | summary | text_len |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xxx | 45 |
| 2 | aaa | 34 |

I am performing some df manipulation by concatenating keywords from different df, like that:

```
keywords = df["keyword"].to_list()
for key in keywords:
    new_df[key] = new_df["summary"].str.lower().str.count(key)
new_df
```

from here I need two separate dataframes to perform few actions (to each of them add some columns, do some calculations etc).

I need a dataframe with occurrences as per given piece of code and a binary dataframe.

WHAT I DID:

1. assign dataframe for occurrences:
   `df_freq = new_df` (because it is already calculated an done)
2. I created another dataframe - binary one - on the top of new_df:

   #select only numeric columns to change them to binary

   numeric_cols = new_df.select_dtypes("number", exclude='float64').columns.tolist()

   new_df_binary = new_df

   new_df_binary['text_length'] = new_df_binary['text_length'].astype(int)

   new_df_binary[numeric_cols] = (new_df_binary[numeric_cols] > 0).astype(int)
3. Everything works fine  - I perform the math I need, but when I want to come back to df_freq - it is no longer dataframe with occurrences.. looks like it changed along with binary code

I need separate tables and perform separate math on them. Do you know how I can avoid this hmm overwriting issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use pandas' `copy` method with the `deep` argument set to `True`:

```
df_freq = new_df.copy(deep=True)
```

Setting `deep=True` (which is the default parameter) ensures that modifications to the data or indices of the copy do not impact the original dataframe.